# How to detect if a result is due to an approximation in floating division?

Tags: python-3.x, graph, precision

From a data set I'm working on I have produced the following graph:[image: exponential decay]

The graph it is constructed as follows: to each element on the data set it is associated the ratio between two natural numbers (some times big numbers) where the numerator is lesser then the denominator. Let be this number k. Then for each value n in [0,1] it is counted how many elements have k>n.

So, while the exponential decay is expected, the jumps come out of the blue. To calculate the ratio between a and b I have just done:`c=a/b`

I'm asking if there is a way to check if the jumps are due to numerical approximation in the division or they are an actual property of my dataset.

Comment: It looks like the jumps are at clean fractions like 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, 1/5, 2/3, etc. Those seem likely to be part of your dataset. What do each of the axes mean?

Comment: On the "x" there is the value n (the treshold value), while on "y" the amount of elements in the data set whose k>n